# apt-get purge, install nginx; reports success but not installed (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, apt, nginx

after removing nginx, I re-installed it with `sudo apt-get install nginx`.

Output indicated that the installation was successful.

But there's no directory `/etc/nginx` and `sudo service nginx start` fails because it can't read the `config` file.

How can I fix this?

Comment: @rakesh -- software-properties packages were installed already, added ppa, updated, re-installed nginx; same problem persists

Comment: @lekensteyn: thanks, I'd just gotten it working by re-installing nginx-common and nginx-full; I guess the -full was unnecessary

Comment: `-full` was indeed unnecessary, it means that it includes additional nginx modules that are not installed with the default package (`nginx`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration files are provided by the `nginx-common` package, not `nginx`. Therefore you have to purge `nginx-common`:

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx-common
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

(`nginx` depends on `nginx-common`, removing `nginx-common` will also remove `nginx`.)

There is no need to add the nginx PPA just for getting back the configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

To Install nginx:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

To start nginx:

```
sudo service nginx start
```

To check the package installation

```
 service nginx status
```